# Random Equation Test. Correct or Wrong answer

Tags: c#, random, output

I have been trying to write a test which involves random numbers to make equations for the user to answer. I have wrote it so that two int are assigned to a random number and the console writes the equation. I have used an if statement for the program to dictate whether the users answer is correct or incorrect. However it is always either correct or incorrect depending on the code i write. I can't write it so that the program decides the answer.

```
        int iE3 = rnd.Next(1, 11);
        int iE13 = rnd.Next(1, 11);
        int iA3 = iE3 * iE13;
        int answer3 = iE3 * iE13;
        Console.WriteLine("The third equation is {0} * {1}", iE3, iE13);
        Console.ReadLine();

        if ( answer3 == iA3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Well done you got it right!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately you got it incorrect.");
        }
```

Comment: I see no attempt to *get input from the user*, other than `ReadLine` where the result is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You are ignoring the users input, you need to assign the result of the ReadLine:

```
int answer3 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Of course with error handling incase they don't enter a number etc...

Comment: I Have tried to impliment the code into the program, However I get this result "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' "

Comment: Then you must not have typed a valid integer - hence the part where I mentioned adding error handling

Comment: If you type a number you will not get that error, if you however type 'a' then you get that error because 'a' is not convertable to a number

Comment: I have now implimented a function to stop it getting errors. However i have tried many combinations of the if statement and it continues to say that the answer is incorrect. How would you recommend putting the if statement?

Comment: Update your question with the new code and we can see